# Angular 6 error: ValidatorFn expected to return a promise

Tags: angular, validation, promise, passwords

I am having an issue whereby a validator function is expecting to return a promise. to my understanding, I am creating a custom validator function that checks if an inputted "New Password" string equals a "ConfirmPassword" string, using a promise. Here's the current state of my code:

**change-password.component.ts**

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { passwordValidator } from './password.validator';

export class ChangePasswordComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(formCreator: FormBuilder) { 

    this.form = formCreator.group({
    oldPassword: ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4) ], passwordValidator.isSameOld],
    newPassword: ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)] ],
    confirmPassword: 
                 ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)], 
                        passwordValidator.isSameNew ] 
    });
  }
```

**password.validator.ts**

*additions made with Jaime's help*

```
    import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, FormControl, ValidatorFn } from "@angular/forms";

    static isSameNew(formFields: FormGroup) : Promise<ValidationErrors | null>{ 
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(formFields.get('newPassword'));

                if (formFields.get('confirmPassword').value !== formFields.get('newPassword').value) {
                    console.log(formFields);

                    resolve({isSameNew: true});
                }

                else resolve(null);
            }, 2000)

        });
    }
```

Can you please help me with debugging? I have tried passing the newPassword into the function by writing

```
    confirmPassword: 
                 ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)], 
                        passwordValidator.isSameNew(newPassword) ]
```

but soon found out that I cannot do it this way because the newPassword property isn't defined until after the form object is defined. I need to use a promise so that I can use an asynchronous callback function to give the 'password mismatch' error message a delay before appearing as to avoid startling the user.

Thanks heaps for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare the values of two different controls, you should attach the validator to the [group](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#group) instead of to one of the controls.

Try something like this:

```
  // Your component constructor:
  constructor(formCreator: FormBuilder) { 
    this.form = formCreator.group(
      {
        oldPassword: ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4) ]],
        newPassword: ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)] ],
        confirmPassword: ['', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)], passwordValidator.isSameNew ] 
      },
      {
        validator: PasswordMatchValidator
      }
    );
  }

  // password-match.validator.ts:
  export function PasswordMatchValidator(formGroup: FormGroup): void {
    const newPassword = formGroup.get('newPassword').value;
    const confirmPassword = formGroup.get('confirmPassword').value;

    formGroup.get('confirmPassword').setErrors(undefined);

    if (newPassword !== confirmPassword) {
      formGroup.get('confirmPassword').setErrors({ match: true });
    }
  }
```

You can use the same approach to compare old and new password and set the `isSameNew` accordingly.

Also note that, if you want to return a promise you should use [AsyncValidatorFn](https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidatorFn) interface instead of [ValidatorFn](https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidatorFn) interface.

Comment: I tried doing this function write up today but formGroup.get('confirmPassword') and formGroup.get('newPassword') return null

Comment: @Bobstar89 can you share a link to your code on JSFiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s4q3u8nh/

I'm fairly new to JSFiddle, so pardon any inefficiencies

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this issue by calling the root method of formFields like so:

```
    static isSameNew(formFields: FormGroup) : Promise<ValidationErrors | null>{ 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        setTimeout(() => {

            if (formFields.root.get('confirmPassword').value !== formFields.root.get('newPassword').value) {
                resolve({isSameNew: true});
            }

            else resolve(null);
        }, 2000)

    });
```

I don't exactly know why using "root" solved my issue but to my awareness each FormGroup knows their parent Form's controls